# How can I stop blocks, which a single Linux process reads, from being cached?

Tags: linux, cache

I have a troublesome virus-checking program that scans the entire filesystem overnight. However, this program causes all the valuable data to be evicted from the server's cache, resulting in significant slowdowns in the morning.

How can I execute this Linux binary in a manner that prevents it from evicting content from the cache?

I would like it to either read directly from the disk without utilizing the cache at all or, preferably, perform reads that do not displace existing data.

Comment: found the answer there lacking, though it really is a duplicate of the linked question.